# Block Mean calculation using Matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I divide an image region, divide it into nxn blocks let us say 4x4 in this case. For each block, calculate the mean value of the block.I will need to convert the block mean into a binary bitmap basing on (pixel value=block mean).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want can be achieved with `imresize`, using the following syntax:

```
N = 100;
n = 4; % the size of your nxn blocks
image = rand(N);
small_image = imresize(image,1/n,'box');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
img = randn(12,12); %// example data
[R C] = size(img);
N = 4; %// block size. Assumed to divide R and C

result_small = blockproc(img,[N N],@(block) mean(block.data(:))); %// R/N x C/N
result = result_small(floor(0:1/N:R/N-1/N)+1,floor(0:1/N:C/N-1/N)+1); %// R x C
```